# Left cosets of a subgroup of $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Assume H is a subgroup of $S_n$ defined in the following way $H=\{\sigma\in S_n;\sigma(n)=n\}$

Prove the following:

(i) For any $ \sigma_1 , \sigma_2 \in S_n$ their left cosets $\sigma_1 H $ and $\sigma_2 H $ are equal if and only if $\sigma_1(n) = \sigma_2(n)$

(ii) That H has exactly n left cosets.

Im kind of confused on this i know that they should be equal if they send n to same value and i know that that there are n choices to send n to so there should be n unique left cosets but im not really sure how to prove eithier.

Comment: $H \simeq S_{n-1}$. From this also you can conclude that $H$ has exactly $n$ left cosets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(ii) follows directly from (i).  For (i), note that $\sigma_1H=\sigma_2H$ if and only if $\sigma_1^{-1} \circ \sigma_2 \in H$, which means that $\sigma_1^{-1}(\sigma_2(n))=n$, so hit both sides with $\sigma_1$.

Comment: does that really show both sides?

Comment: Yes, it does.  Everything is reversible.

Comment: Thats painfully obvious when i see it written out, will accept when it lets me.